# DataMagic for nested yml file

Tags: ruby

I have a yml file like below.

```
accounts:
  account1:
    name: vink
    age: 26
  account2:
    name: pink
    age: 27
```

In order to read the data thru DATAMAGIC method, Please let me know how
code flow should be in ruby?

I knew that if we have only one key in yml file.

Then Code is..

```
DataMagic.load("ymlfile.yml")
variablename=data_for(:accounts)
```

But now i have  key "accounts" and sub key "account1". In this case I
wanted to read name and age values.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your required data as below:

```
res = DataMagic.load("ymlfile.yml")
res["accounts"]["account1"]["name"] #=> "vink"
res["accounts"]["account2"]["name"] #=> "pink"
```

Hope that answers your question.